# multiple requestLocationUpdates are running

Tags: android, location, android-service, android-fusedlocation

I use fusedLocation API to request location updates. For some reason I start `requestLocationUpdates` within a background service. As I know there is just one instance of any android service in a system. But every time I call this service using `startService()`, a new location listener is created and so multiple location updates are working parallel. How can I check if there is another **mLocationRequest** before creating a new one?

```
public class LocationService extends Service implements
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
    LocationListener {

    //Service parameters
    final Context context = this;
    boolean isWorking = false;
    boolean jobCancelled = false;
    public boolean mustStop=false;
    GoogleApiClient mLocationClient;
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    public String CurrentLocation = null;
  //Service methods
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        LocationStartPoint();
        return START_STICKY;
     }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    //Location API
    public void LocationStartPoint(){
        mLocationClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();

        mLocationRequest.setInterval(30000);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(20000);
        int priority = LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY;
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(priority);
        mLocationClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle dataBundle) {

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return;
            }
        }
        else {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationClient, mLocationRequest, this);
        }

    }

//other methods are out of context of this question

}
```

and this is how I use this service and a user may try running this service multiple times by clicking a start button:

```
Intent startIntent=new Intent(this, LocationService.class);
startService(startIntent);
```